# Java. Как реализован метод isAlive()?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, *где можно посмотреть реализацию метода `isAlive()?`* Единственное, что нашел – это исходный код из пакета `java.util.Thread`:

```
public final native boolean isAlive();
```

Дальше тупик.

P.S. Поиск в гугле результатов не дал.

Comment: в исходниках JVM

Comment: А исходники где? Я бы тоже посмотрел, как все остальные методы  и классы реализованы.

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/ см. jdk/src/share/native/java/lang

Comment: Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Копался в файлах: openJDK-7\openjdk\jdk\src\share\native\java\lang\Thread.c  и openJDK-7\openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\thread.hpp, но если честно толком ничего не понял. Сложновато для меня. Ещё раз спасибо.